# Write vector as sum $w = u + v$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let L be the line $x + 2y = 0$.

Write the vector $w = (-4,7)$ as a sum $w = u + v$, where $u$ is parallel to $L$ and $v$ is perpendicular to $L$.

I think I'll need to use $w=\operatorname{proj}L(w)+\operatorname{proj}L⊥(w)$

To calculate $\operatorname{proj}L(w)$ I'll need to use  $$\operatorname{proj}A(B) = \frac{A\cdot B}{A^2} \cdot A$$

However, $L$ is a line and not a vector, therefore I don't know what $A$ should be, also I do not know the formula for when $v$ is perpendicular to $L$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

If $L:x+2y=0,$ then the vector $(1,2)$ is perpendicular to the line $L$.

If $u$ is parallel to $L$, then $u=cL_D$ or $L_D=cu$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and direction vector $L_D$ for the line $L$.

If $v$ is perpendicular to $L$, then $v\cdot L_D=0$ for some direction vector $L_D$ of the line $L.$

Use the condition that $u+v=w=(-4,7)$ to determine $u,v$ above.

Comment: So then I get $(-4,7)-(1,2) = (-5,5)$ did I do it correctly?